# How do I make a local execution action without account linking?

Tags: google-smart-home

I am creating a home appliance to connect to google home. Can the device be cloudless using the local execution? The documentation and the example on GitHub suggest we need an oAuth server. Because the speaker is communicating directly with the appliance, is account linking even necessary? If an account is a must, how can we setup a local execution project that uses google sign for assistant? I am not seeing that option available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Local execution](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/local) still requires a cloud service as a backend and the cloud service will be used as a fallback if the local execution is not working. As such, account linking is also requried.

Comment: Does it always require my own oAuth or can I use google sign in?

Comment: You need to provide OAuth that is not Google Sign-in directly